# Comma and Tab separated file into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this data set, I need to have put it in a dictionary that gives me like this {'1: xx, xx', '2:xx, xx'} etc what can i possibly do to achieve that as i need to remove the word bag, weight and value, Thanks in advance an i appreciate the help.

```
bag 1:
  weight: 9.4
  value: 57
 bag 2:
  weight: 7.4
  value: 94
 bag 3:
  weight: 7.7
  value: 59
 bag 4:
  weight: 7.4
  value: 83
 bag 5:
  weight: 2.9
  value: 82
 bag 6:
  weight: 1.1
  value: 91
 bag 7:
  weight: 7.3
  value: 42
 bag 8:
  weight: 9.0
  value: 84
 bag 9:
  weight: 8.1
  value: 85
 bag 10:
  weight: 7.2
  value: 18
 bag 11:
  weight: 7.5
  value: 94
 bag 12:
  weight: 4.2
  value: 18
 bag 13:
  weight: 4.4
  value: 31
 bag 14:
  weight: 5.7
  value: 27
 bag 15:
  weight: 2.0
  value: 31
 bag 16:
  weight: 2.0
  value: 42
```

Ive tried to think about it with this code but its producing nothing and i dont know how to fix it

```py
capacity = 285
val = 0
weight = 0
b ='bag '
w = 'weight'
v = 'value'
Bag_dict = {}

with open('BankProblem.txt') as f:
    current_id = ''
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('bag '):
            current_id = line.replace(':', '')
            if line.startswith('weight:'):
                Bag_dict.append((current_id, line))
                if line.startswith('value:'):
                    Bag_dict.append((current_id, weight, line))
print(Bag_dict)
```

Comment: You could do this in one line if the data were written out in something more standard like CSV or JSON -- do you have the ability to change the code that writes out the data?  Also, do you have the actual text, or do you just have the data in PNG form?  Having to OCR it adds another level of complexity.

Comment: I have the actual text, sorry for not specifying its about 300 lines of the same format, how can i use it to place it in a dictionary as i cannot play with the data set? bag 1:
  weight: 9.4
  value: 57
 bag 2:
  weight: 7.4
  value: 94
 bag 3:
  weight: 7.7
  value: 59
 bag 4:
  weight: 7.4
  value: 83
 bag 5:
  weight: 2.9
  value: 82
 bag 6:
  weight: 1.1
  value: 91
 bag 7:
  weight: 7.3
  value: 42

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I do apologies as this is my first time posting a question and i had no clue on how to use this

Comment: `if line.startswith('weight:')` - All the lines in the file start with a space (or multiple spaces) - you should probably strip the whitespace from each line before testing it ... `for line in f: line = line.strip(); if line......`.

Comment: If you search SO for questions about finding things in files or extracting things from files and read the answers you'll probably run into this - whitespace being [stripped](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) from a line before anything else is done.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do,

```
data = {}

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    recentDict = {}
    recentindex = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'bag ' in line:
            recentindex = line.split('bag ')[1].split(":")[0]
        if 'weight' in line:
            weight = line.split("weight: ")[1].split("\n")[0]
            recentDict['weight'] = float(weight)
        if 'value' in line:
            value = line.split("value: ")[1].split("\n")[0]
            recentDict['value'] = int(value)
            recentDict = {}
            data[recentindex] = recentDict
print(data)
```

It reads in each line, makes a dictionary with the fields weight and value and then appends it to a list. The index of the value is bag - 1.

Comment: Thats great man,, but is there any way to do is as Bag num : weight, val so a single dictionary entry would be 1 : 3.5,59? as i do need to keep the bag number.

Comment: Sure, check my edit. However I would consider your use case as you are adding unneeded complexity by storing your data in a dictionary when an array represents it just fine.

Comment: I checked the data your last edited code doesnt produce the first bag and the output is given like this after the whole data set is ran : {'1': {'weight': 7.4, 'value': 94}, '2': {'weight': 7.7, 'value': 59}, '3': {'weight': 7.4, 'value': 83}, '4': {'weight': 2.9, 'value': 82}, '5': {'weight': 1.1, 'value': 91}, '6': {'weight': 7.3, 'value': 42}, '7': {'weight': 9.0, 'value': 84}, '8': {'weight': 8.1, 'value': 85}, '9': {'weight': 7.2, 'value': 18}, '10': {'weight': 7.5, 'value': 94}, ', '99': {'weight': 3.9, 'value': 59}, '100': {}}